# What does this IOS app crash report mean?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, crash-reports, watchdog

The phone is an iPhone 4, which doesn't support iOS 8. The app is iOS 7 compatible and the previous version of the app ran on the iPhone 4.

I can install it on an iPhone 4, but once I log into the app, it crashes. Here's a copy of the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 7083D8D9-A834-49D2-9BAE-740C4381B1ED
CrashReporter Key:   31b0b47127ebc15ed8ec25b14f923e5fb96fada5
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:              [1081]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/BDB720EA-C2C8-427A-    BC3B-29B4A7679D1E/
Identifier:          ApnApp
Version:             14.5 (14.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-01 09:18:04.436 +1000
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
[1081] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x145d4bf0> identifier: Suspending process:     [1081] permittedBackgroundDuration: 10.000000 reason: suspend owner   pid:28 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownCPU  preventThrottleDownUI    preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 1.410 (user 1.410, system 0.000),     28% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.005, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38c76aa8 0x38c76000 + 2728
1   lib.dylib               0x38bc1f74 0x38bad000 + 85876
2   CFNetwork                       0x2dabc868 0x2daba000 + 10344
3   Foundation                      0x2e8a851e 0x2e831000 + 488734
4                           0x000eb6ea 0xe4000 + 30442
5                           0x00109a9c 0xe4000 + 154268
6   UIKit                           0x30949b04 0x30728000 + 2235140
7   UIKit                           0x30949948 0x30728000 + 2234696
8   UIKit                           0x3085103a 0x30728000 + 1216570
9   UIKit                           0x30903352 0x30728000 + 1946450
10  UIKit                           0x307b26d2 0x30728000 + 566994
11  UIKit                           0x3072b536 0x30728000 + 13622
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2dee1252 0x2de42000 + 651858
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2dedebf4 0x2de42000 + 642036
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2dedef36 0x2de42000 + 642870
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2de49eba 0x2de42000 + 32442
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2de49c9e 0x2de42000 + 31902
17  GraphicsServices                0x32d4f65e 0x32d46000 + 38494
18  UIKit                           0x30796148 0x30728000 + 450888
19                          0x000e8f66 0xe4000 + 20326
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x38bd3ab4 0x38bd2000 + 6836

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38c76808 0x38c76000 + 2056
1   lib.dylib               0x38bc2de8 0x38bad000 + 89576
2   lib.dylib               0x38bb1f6e 0x38bad000 + 20334

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38c76a58 0x38c76000 + 2648
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38c76854 0x38c76000 + 2132
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dee0846 0x2de42000 + 649286
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dedef6c 0x2de42000 + 642924
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2de49eba 0x2de42000 + 32442
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2de49c9e 0x2de42000 + 31902
6   Foundation                      0x2e88a082 0x2e831000 + 364674
7   Foundation                      0x2e8ffa5a 0x2e831000 + 846426
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38cf2916 0x38cf0000 + 10518
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38cf2886 0x38cf0000 + 10374
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38cf0aa0 0x38cf0000 + 2720

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38c89434 0x38c76000 + 78900
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2dee4708 0x2de42000 + 665352
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38cf2916 0x38cf0000 + 10518
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38cf2886 0x38cf0000 + 10374
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38cf0aa0 0x38cf0000 + 2720

Thread 4 ......

No thread state (register information) available
```

What could be the reason for it crashing?

Comment: That exception indicates that your app was running in the background for more than 10 minutes.  You should look at your app delegate background methods and see why this could be

Comment: Re: `The phone is Iphone 4 and as you all know that doesn't have IOS 7.` The iPhone 4 supports up to iOS 7.1.2.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the advise. I can tell you that it happens in a minute as soon as I log in and funny though the app runs perfectly on Iphone 4s and plus.

Comment: @Paulw11 there is a timer in the background, however, this timer gets fired whether there is set up initially from the server to run once the user logs in. I haven't set up the timer yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think its related with a long running task, you should not make synchronous things in app delegate or first screen your app. It can occur on slow connections etc. (if its network related job.) try to make async calls. App cant even start because of that long running task. If an app takes long time to load, ios automatically terminates it.

Comment: The app establishes a connection through the server and starts capturing the need data and stores in the local db once the user logs in. It is sure that wifi has a strong connectivity so the phone hooks up the wifi. What does it occur in an IOS 7 phone and works perfectly in IOS 8 phones?

Comment: @mehmet you can see in the debugger which line causing error, add an exception breakpoint in xcode to check which line causes error.

Comment: I had no chance to reach out the code to find out the error. Thanks for your advise anyway.